# repeated-measures linear mixed-effect model

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have two soil treatments: CT and NT.

For each treatment, I have 11 CO2 measurements taken in 7 times, i.e. 11 "replicates" for 7 dates.

I'd like to evaluate if the measurements are different in time for the two treatments.

I have:

- replicates(11)=random factor;
- days=repeated measure factor (fixed factor)
- treatment = between subject factor (fixed factor)
- CO2 = Co2 emission measures (=dependent variable)

Is it correct to consider this as a nested two-level repeated measures ANOVA?

Is it correct to use the following R syntax?

```
m1 <- lmer(CO2~days*treatment+(days|replicates),mydata)
```

Is this a random intercept and slope model with replicates nested in treatment?

Is it correct to say that this model accounts for:

- the main effect of treatment and time and
- the interaction between the two?

What would be the difference between m1 and m2?

```
m2 <- lmer(CO2~days*treatment+(1|replicates),mydata)
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is it correct to consider this as a nested two-level repeated measures ANOVA?

No, it is a linear mixed effects model.

> Is it correct to use the following R syntax?
>
> `m1 <- lmer(CO2~days*treatment+(days|replicates),mydata)`

It is correct if you wish to account for clustering, ie repeated measures, within each replicate, and allow the slope of `days` to vary between replicates.

> Is this a random intercept and slope model with replicates nested in treatment?

It is a random intercept and slope model, but observations are nested within replicates.

> Is it correct to say that this model accounts for:
>
> - the main effect of treatment and time and
> - the interaction between the two?

Yes, these are modeled as fixed effects.

> What would be the difference between m1 and m2?
>
> m2 <- lmer(CO2~days*treatment+(1|replicates),mydata)

`m2` is a random intercept model, it accounts for clustering (repeated measures) but the slopes, are assumed to be constant for east replicate. `m1` allows the slope for `days` to vary between clusters (replicates in your case).